# javascript slide in div on image click?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the yellow div to slide up when clicking on the tree icon in the modal possibly without jQuery but I can't get it to work.

You can see the page I'm building here by clicking the first icon from left https://vivere-albero-verona.netlify.app/

I've tried different solutions but here's the code I have right now

html:

```
<div id="alberi" class="alberi">
      <div id="acero">
          <img src="./images/tree.png">
          <h1>ACERO CAMPESTRE</h1>
          <h2>Altezza: 7,0m</h2>
          <h2>Ingombro: 2,0m</h2>
          <h2>Fornitore</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.alberi{
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    height: 0px;
    width: 90.9%;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.slided{
    height: 270px;}
```

js:

```
const sezionealberi = document.querySelector('#alberi')
const pulsantealberi = document.querySelector('#m-tree')

pulsantealberi.addEventListener('click', primavera)

let mezzastagione = 1;

function primavera()
{
    if(mezzastagione == 1) 
    { 
        sezionealberi.innerHTML = `<class = "alberi slided">`;
        mezzastagione = 0;
    }
    
    else{
        sezionealberi.innerHTML = `<class = "alberi">`;
        mezzastagione = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be assigning to innerHTML to change a class attribute, and should be using `classList` instead:

```
function primavera()
{
    if(mezzastagione == 1) 
    { 
        sezionealberi.classList.add('slided');
        mezzastagione = 0;
    }
    
    else{
        sezionealberi.classList.remove('slided')
        mezzastagione = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too but I still would get a type error "Cannot read property 'classList' of null" and I don't understand why

Comment: That's because your querySelector isn't finding the element (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has provided great insights about your code, but I would like to help you solve the "Cannot read property 'classList' of null" problem.

You're trying to get the element before it's loaded, use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) to get the element after it's loaded on the page. Refer to the code bellow:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const sezionealberi = document.querySelector('#alberi')
    const pulsantealberi = document.querySelector('#m-tree')

    // mezzastagione == 1 is redundant use a boolean instead
    let mezzastagione = true;

    const primavera = () => {
        if(mezzastagione) { 
            sezionealberi.classList.add('slided');
            mezzastagione = false;

        } else {
            sezionealberi.classList.remove('slided');
            mezzastagione = true;
        }
    }

    pulsantealberi.addEventListener('click', primavera);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm still getting the 'cannot read properties of null classlist though